# How to use function from another JS file?

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

I am trying to use  bubble.js function and have the function of bubble.js apply to my new js file called bubbleChanged.js file

bubble.js:

```
let bubble = document.getElementById("speach-bubble");
let noDisplay; bubble.style.display ="none";

const delay = setTimeout(bubbleAnimate,1500)

export function bubbleAnimate()
{
    noDisplay = bubble.style.display ="block";
    bubble.style.animation="slidein 1.6s 1";

}
```

bubbleChanged.js:

```
import{bubbleAnimate} from '../js/bubble.js';

let form = document.querySelector('.form')

form.addEventListener('submit' , (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();

  const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  let textChange= document.getElementById('speach-bubble');

  textChange.innerHTML = "Welcome to your To-do app \n" + input;
  bubbleAnimate()
});

bubbleAnimate()
{
    textChnage.style.display ="block";
    textChnage.style.animation="slidein 1.6s 1";
}
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here?  should the `bubbleAnimate()` be inside the event listener?

In short, when the speech bubble is updated after user input the same animation needs to happen when the speech bubble changes

Comment: Use export default and remove the curly braces

Comment: not sure I follow, do you mean this ```export default bubbleAnimate()```

Comment: Yep, and remove the curly braces in the import